# converting and concatenating a clob column using dbms_lob.substr gives 'ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long' error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written down a query as

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.last_call_et,
s.sid ,
s.sql_id,
to_clob(dbms_lob.substr(sq.sql_fulltext,4000,1)) ||
to_clob(dbms_lob.substr(sq.sql_fulltext,4000,4001)) SQL_TEXT,
s.username,
s.status,
s.blocking_session,
s.BLOCKING_INSTANCE,
sq.LAST_ACTIVE_TIME,
NULL
FROM gv$session s,
    gv$sql sq
  WHERE sq.address    = s.sql_address
AND sq.hash_value   = s.SQL_HASH_VALUE
AND sq.sql_id       = s.sql_id
AND s.status        = 'ACTIVE'
AND s.last_call_et >= 500
AND s.sql_id       IS NOT NULL 
AND SQ.SQL_TEXT NOT LIKE '%$%';
```

This gives me the ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long error probably because the SQL_TEXT column in my query above exceeds 4000 characters.
Please suggest a way around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can concatenate Clobs.  Tried this, and it worked,

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.last_call_et,
s.sid ,
s.sql_id,
dbms_lob.substr(sq.sql_fulltext,4000,1) ||
dbms_lob.substr(sq.sql_fulltext,4000,4001) SQL_TEXT,
s.username,
s.status,
s.blocking_session,
s.BLOCKING_INSTANCE,
sq.LAST_ACTIVE_TIME,
NULL
FROM gv$session s,
    gv$sql sq
  WHERE sq.address    = s.sql_address
AND sq.hash_value   = s.SQL_HASH_VALUE
AND sq.sql_id       = s.sql_id
AND s.status        = 'ACTIVE'
AND s.last_call_et >= 500
AND s.sql_id       IS NOT NULL 
AND SQ.SQL_TEXT NOT LIKE '%$%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the concatenation operator you used ('||') is defined on VARCHAR2, but not on CLOBS> Therefore, Oracle does an implicit type conversion to VARCHAR2, which is limited to 4000 bytes in size.
You should use DBMS_LOB.APPEND to concatenate LOBs.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#BABEAJAD

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried this out in my query above
     DBMS_LOB.APPEND(dbms_lob.substr(sq.sql_fulltext,4000,1),dbms_lob.substr(sq.sql_fulltext,4000,4001)) SQL_TEXT

but it gave me an error saying - 
DBMS_LOB"."APPEND": invalid identifier

Am I using it in a wrong way or something?